# what is the difference among amazon inspector vs trusted advisor vs cloudwatch vs Personal Health Dashboard vs AWS cloudtrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi dear StackOverflow community,

These below amazon concepts are confusing to me, I do not get to establish the key difference among them at once:
Amazon inspector vs trusted advisor vs cloudwatch vs Personal Health Dashboard vs AWS cloud trail.

Could you help me to get clarity in the key difference among them?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Trusted Advisor

**Trusted Advisor** offers recommendations to lower cost and improve security, performance and fault tolerance. Some are provided for free, while all of the recommendations are only available to subscribers to AWS Support.

[image: AWS Trusted Advisor]

#### Personal Health Dashboard

[AWS Personal Health Dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-personal-health-dashboard-status-you-can-relate-to/) shows issues and outages that might affect your usage of AWS services.

[image: AWS Personal health dashboard]

#### Amazon CloudWatch

**Amazon CloudWatch** stores metrics and allows Alarms to be configured based on those metrics. Many AWS services send metrics to CloudWatch, such as Amazon EC2 providing CPU metrics and Amazon S3 providing storage metrics. It also has CloudWatch Logs that can store log files and respond to log messages, and CloudWatch Events that can trigger actions in response to certain events).

[image: Amazon CloudWatch dashboard]

#### AWS CloudTrail

**AWS CloudTrail** is an audit trail of API calls made to AWS. It tracks details of all requests, such as the user, source IP, timestamp, request parameters and the success of the API call. Just like a security company keeps track of every time you use a swipe-card, CloudTrail keep track of every time a request is made to an AWS service.

[image: AWS CloudTrail]

#### Amazon Inspector

**Amazon Inspector** runs on Amazon EC2 instances and scans the computer for known vulnerabilities in the operating system and applications.

[image: Amazon Inspector findings]

Comment: Thank you very much @John Rotenstein for your response, but the recommendations are given by Trusted Advisor is not because of found issues? Thank you once more time.

Comment: For a list of items checked by Trusted Advisor, see: [AWS Trusted Advisor Best Practice Checklist - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/trusted-advisor/best-practice-checklist/)

Comment: Thank you very much @John Rotenstein. Have a nice day.

Comment: one of the best answer read, so far on AWS. Ty.